# Grid layout with absolute position not working

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to add an element with a grid in absolute position. but not works as expected. according to my requirement `absolute` class dev needs to sit on top of the grid. how to get it?

```css
.content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "one" "two" "three" "absolute";
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.one,
.two,
.three{
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.one{
  grid-area: one;
}

.two{
  grid-area: two;
}

.three{
  grid-area: three;
}

.absolute{
  position: absolute;
  left:auto; right: auto;
  top:0;
  width: 100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="content">
      <div class='one'>one</div>
      <div class="two">two</div>
      <div class="three">three</div>
      <div class="absolute">absolute</div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you attach the expected result? It seems fine on me.

Comment: It's left aligned instead of center

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width), it is needed to set `left` and `right` of css attribute to `0` on `.absolute` class.

```css
.content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "one" "two" "three" "absolute";
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.one,
.two,
.three{
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.one{
  grid-area: one;
}

.two{
  grid-area: two;
}

.three{
  grid-area: three;
}

.absolute{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  width: 100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
      <div class='one'>one</div>
      <div class="two">two</div>
      <div class="three">three</div>
      <div class="absolute">absolute</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean `justify-content` not working. It's set as `center` for now and it does not affect on the `absolute` position element.